# LiveCode external example for XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, livecode, externals

I thought I'd try writing a simple C++ external for LiveCode. The HelloWorld example given in the tutorial with ExternalEnvironmentsv3 doesn't compile under Xcode 7.2, all sorts of syntax errors (missing {} and semicolons, Bool for bool --- is this VisualStudio code?? ---, deprecated ColorPicker library warnings, and more).

I am familiar with Objective-C, so some are easy to fix but a long time since I did any C++ and there is one syntax error (expecting an expression before EXTERNAL_BEGIN_DECLARATIONS) I can't figure out what it wants; also a "missing line-end at end of file"(???) Since others don't appear to have reported any problem, perhaps am I overlooking something trivial? Or has the sample been updated? Or better, can anyone point me to a simple cpp example which actually works under Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use the old externals environment stacks to generate projects. I just start a new bundle project and add external.c & h to it. You may be interested in my [Xcode templates](https://github.com/montegoulding/livecode-external-templates) which help you start an Xcode project in the various ways it can be done.

Comment: Thanks Monte. I eventually worked out that was the way to go.